# Why Evolution is used? what it's need?

Tags: evolution

I have installed evolution.
but,
Why evolution is used?
why it is needed?
How to use it?

Comment: Evolution is a desktop mail client.

Comment: and it is used for what?

Comment: E-mail, that is why it is an mail client, why install it if you don't know what it is ?

Comment: Welcome to AU. I do not want to detract from @Julian Stirling 's correct response to you, but a lot of people could have answered you and probably chose not to. Is searching the web or even looking for package information beyond you ?

Comment: Probably @Cbhihe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evolution is a desktop email client. It is useful if you want to manage your email from a program (similar to using outlook on a windows PC) rather than using a web interface. It can also manage calendars, and with the `evolution-ews` extension it has exchange support which is useful for many people in businesses who use exchange for their business email.

If you do all of your email and contacts via a web interface it may be of no use to you, but it is a good fully featured mail client.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of the answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)